# Correct usage of Meteor wrapAsync

Tags: meteor

The following is what I am trying to do:

```
var joinNetwork = function (obj) {
  Meteor.call("joinNetwork", {
    userId: obj.userId,
    domain: obj.domain
  }, function (err, networkId) {
    return networkId;
  });
}    

Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
  var userId = user._id;
  var email = options.email;
  var domain = Utils.getDomain(email);
  var joinNetworkSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(joinNetwork);

  // works fine until here

  var networkId = joinNetworkSync({
    userId: userId,
    domain: domain
  });

  // never get here
  debugger
```

As you can see, after I call `joinNetworkSync` I never reach the code after it. In other words, `networkId` is never available. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return from a `wrapAsync` you have to call a callback passed to that function:

```
Meteor.wrapAsync(function (obj, done) {
  Meteor.call("joinNetwork", {
    userId: obj.userId,
    domain: obj.domain
  }, function (err, networkId) {
    done(networkId);
  });
})
```

You don't need wrap async here dough. When you call meteor methods server side, they return like normal functions. You can just do this if the `joinNetwork` method is properly defined:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
  var userId = user._id;
  var email = options.email;
  var domain = Utils.getDomain(email);
  var networkId = Meteor.call("joinNetwork", {
    userId: obj.userId,
    domain: obj.domain
  });
  ...
})
```

Comment: I didn't know `Meteor.call` doesn't need a callback on the server side. One additional question. If that Meteor.call returns an error instead, how do I access it? Should I wrap it around try and catch block?

Answer (score 0):

I think your sync version of joinNetwork is not returning anything. You placed a return inside another function, the callback of joinNetwork. Try splitting the next part up in another function and call that inside the callback function using the networkId.